# Is it preferred to initialize a WPF user control in its Loaded event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

Assume I have a WPF UserControl looking like this:

```
public partial class SensorSideView
{
    public SensorSideView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += SensorSideView_Loaded;
        Unloaded += SensorSideView_Unloaded;
    }

    void SensorSideView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var section in SensorSideViewController.CurrentSideview.Sections)
            LoadSection(section);
        ...
    }

    void SensorSideView_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearGui();
    }

    private void LoadSection(Section sec)
    {
        var section = new SectionView(sec);
        section.MouseEnter += ucSection_MouseEnter;
        section.MouseLeave += ucSection_MouseLeave;
        section.MouseLeftButtonDown += ucSection_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        section.Unloaded += ucSection_Unloaded;
        section.Loaded += ucSection_Loaded;
        SectionsCanvas.Children.Add(section);
    }

    private void ClearGui()
    {
        foreach (Section sec in SectionsCanvas.Children)
        {
            sec?.RemoveEventHandler();
        }
        SectionsCanvas.Children.Clear();

        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor is only used sparsely, to set up the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` event handlers. The bulk of the setup is instead deferred to the `Loaded` event handler.

I wonder, is this a common or recommended pattern in WPF? Couldn't I just initialize my control once in its constructor, as you would normally with any other C# class, rather than having to reinitialize it each time the user opens it?

The reason I ask is because I have inherited a project where this pattern is very prevalent.

I read somewhere that WPF objects could be re-used by the framework under the hood, which is why I'm hesitant to make the radical change and move the initialization logic from the `Loaded` handler to the constructor.

What's the general guideline in WPF for constructing a complex user control and its instance variables?

Comment: Your merely moving the delay not _fixing_ it.  Perhaps you need to add some true deferred initialisation?

Comment: There is no general pattern. Here it seems that due to the cleanup that's done in Unloaded, rebuilding the view in Loaded is necessary when the control is shown another time. However, is the cleanup really necessary? If not, you could drop the whole Unloaded code, and move the Loaded code to the constructor.

Comment: Even with cleanup, I can't see it would take _"half a second or more"_. Is the code doing something more complex or lengthy than what is being posted here?

Comment: @MickyD My question is just if there's anything technically in WPF that makes one or the other pattern preferable. Or is it just a balance between memory and speed? In this case, I could keep a reference to the user control alive and sacrifice some memory (assuming I moved the initialization to the constructor). But generally, is there anything in WPF that makes putting it in `Loaded` preferred? As I said, this pattern is used very extensively in this project, and I'm just trying to figure out why its original authors would complicate things so much.

Comment: I hear you.  You would probably be better splitting this into two questions - one for the delay problem and another for best practice. One reason I prefer Loaded over constructor init, is that the code executing int he former knows that the control is  now fully laid out and visible - useful if you need to know where elements are located

Answer (score 0):

---

This is a summary of my comments below the OP's question

---

You would probably be better splitting this into two questions - one for the delay problem and another for best practice.

> Is it preferred to initialize a WPF user control in its Loaded event handler?

As with most things, it depends.

One reason I prefer `Loaded` over constructor init, is that the code executing in the former knows that the control is now fully laid out and visible - useful if you need to know where elements are located. [1]

Another good reason for not putting stuff in the constructor is that it will be executed as soon as you instantiate the control rather than when it is visible.

If you have complex control hierarchies where each control has their init in the constructor, then instantiating the very first control in the tree may take a noticeable time.

### Delay

> half a second or more

Going by what code you have posted I am not sure why you are encountering this delay.  You don't appear to be doing anything special.  Like I said *"You would probably be better splitting this into two questions - one for the delay problem and another for best practice"*

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx